# ReactJS redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, reactjs, react-router

I'm using `ReactJS` and `react-router` in my application. I need to do next thing: when user open the page - to check, if he logged in or no, and if yes, then to do redirect to `/auth` page. I'm doing next thing:

```
componentWillMount: function() {
    if (sessionStorage["auth"] == null) {
        this.transitionTo("/auth");
    }
},
```

In browser url it really do redirect to `/auth`, render the `/auth` page and after override it with current component. So here the question: how to cancel rendering for the current component, or how to do redirect in other way? Thanks.

Comment: I faced a similar problem and based my solution on a react-router example available here: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow/app.js

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the react-router example auth-with-shared-root: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-with-shared-root

What they basically do is to check on an enter of a route where to go. Take a look in file `config/routes.js` line 36, 51 and 89:

```
{ onEnter: redirectToLogin,
      childRoutes: [
        // Protected nested routes for the dashboard
        { path: '/page2',
          getComponent: (location, cb) => {
            require.ensure([], (require) => {
              cb(null, require('../components/PageTwo'))
            })
          }
        }
        // other protected routes...
     ]
}
```

This route will call function redirectToLogin when the route `/page2` is entered or pushed to. The function can than check, if the user is authenticated with `auth.loggedIn()`

```
function redirectToLogin(nextState, replace) {
  if (!auth.loggedIn()) {
    replace({
      pathname: '/login',
      state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
    })
  }
}
```

If the user is not logged in, the function will replace the route to `/login`, where the user can authenticates itself.